# git add only some changed files

Tags: git, version-control

I have a remote branch in Git called development and also local development branch. I modified lets say 3 files:

```
git status
modified file1
modified file2
modified file3
```

now I want to add and commit only file1 and push it to remote branch(file2 and file3 will be added later but not now). I try to push it but git doesn't allow to push because remote head is ahead than my local. Then I tried doing `git fetch` and `git rebase` but then, git says I have untracked files. Git suggested to stash them. I am new to git and what I know so far is `git stash` is to save the working changes in case of switching another branch. In my case I am not switching my branch. Is it safe to do proceed with `git stash`? or are there some other ways? I appreciate your explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before push, you need to commit your changes. It's done locally by:

```
#add files to specific commit
git add file1

# commit added files
git commit -m "init commit"

# stash file2 file3
git stash

# now, when working dir is clean you can safly pull updates from remote repo
git pull

# push your changes (your commit) to remote repo
git push origin master

#return file2 file3 changes
git stash apply
```

Comment: It was stated that he didn't want to commit all the files at this time. I think stash would be a better option here...

Comment: To answer the OP you can change the add line to only include the one required file, the rest of the commands should do exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: what I wanna do is rabase but my working dir is not clean because I didn't add 2 files that I changed , thats why I am asking about statch ??

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively stage files.

For example, let's say in the first commit you only wanted to use `file1` and push only that:

```
git add file1
git commit -m "first bit of changes"
git push
```

With Git, you can stage files at a very granular level which allows you craft your commits in a logical way.

As for the other part of the question...

> I try to push it but git doesn't allow to push because remote hed is
>   ahed than my local

Yes, this is definitly a good use-case for `stash`.

Do this:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: Wouldn't pull be sufficient here, without having to do a reset?

Comment: Yes, `pull` almost certainly would work. Just wasn't sure if the OP had his tracking branches set up correctly...

Comment: @CyberneticianDave I went ahead and changed it to `pull`

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink  still my question is does it work "git push" if the remote branch is ahead ?

Comment: @Lakshi, for git push you first want to get your local branch in sync with it's remote counterpart. So, first stash your local changes to get them out of the way (if they are untracked files use `git stash -u`), then `pull` to get your local branch updated, then `stash pop` to get your changes back. After that you can selectively stage (`add`) to only commit some of your files.